# Credentials for gcp in eclipse

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I got this error when I'm setting the

> The method setCredentials(Credentials) in the type ServiceOptions.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (GoogleCredential)

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
            .setCredentials(credentials)
            .build()
            .getService();
```

Comment: Show the code that creates `credentials`. Your `StorageOptions` code appears correct. The problem is probably that you created the wrong `credentials` type.

Comment: Can you specify exactly what are you trying to achieve? Do you have a private key .json file?